# iOS fixed width ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to achieve the following with auto layout.

```
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|    ScrollView     |
|                   |
|                   | 
|                   |
|                   | 
---------------------
|                   |
|     Content       |
|                   |
---------------------
```

The `ScrollView` has a width equal to the screen size and the content inside the `ScrollView` extends the screen. I do not want the user to be able to scroll horizontally.

I have tried

1. Put a `View` inside of the `ScrollView` and set both of them to have leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to 0. Then I try to dynamically set the width of the Content and `ScrollView` to the ScreenSize.
2. Simply surround my page's content in a `ScrollView` set it to have leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to 0. Then I try to dynamically set the width of the `ScrollView` to the ScreenSize.

Both of the following result in something like this...

[image]

Notice how everything is centered horizontally like I have set it up to be, yet the horizontal scrollbar is present and you can scroll into a blank screen.

Comment: Have you tried to setup equal width constraint between scroll and view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably set the wrong content size for the scrollview and hence it is scrolling horizontally.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```